# Creating a struct that conforms to the encodable protocol gives me an error due to a timestamp being a variable. Is there a way to fix this?

Tags: ios, swift

```
import Firebase
import UIKit
```

//I followed the information you gave me. I am unsure if I have done that correctly or as you were expecting it. But, it gives the same error for codable. "Type post doesn't conform to protocol decodable".

import Firebase
import UIKit

```
struct Post: Codable {
    var caption: String
    var likes: Int
    var imageUrl: String
    var ownerUid: String
    var postId: String
    var ownerImageUrl: String
    var ownerUsername: String
    var didLike = false
    var hashtags: [String]
    var activity: [String]
    var video: String
    var videoURL: URL
    var videoFileExtension: String?
    var music: String
    private var timestampDate: Date
    var timestamp: Timestamp { Timestamp(date: timestampDate) }?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case caption
        case likes
        case imageUrl
        case ownerUid
       case timestamp
        case postId
        case ownerImageUrl
        case ownerUsername
        case didLike
        case hashtags
        case activity
        case video
        case videoURL
        case videoFileExtension
        case music
        
    }
    init(postId: String, dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.postId = dictionary["postId"] as? String ?? ""
        self.caption = dictionary["caption"] as? String ?? ""
        self.likes = dictionary["likes"] as? Int ?? 0
        self.imageUrl = dictionary["imageUrl"] as? String ?? ""
        self.ownerUid = dictionary["ownerUid"] as? String ?? ""
        self.ownerImageUrl = dictionary["ownerImageUrl"] as? String ?? ""
        self.ownerUsername = dictionary["ownerUsername"] as? String ?? ""
        self.hashtags = dictionary["hashtags"] as? [String] ?? [String]()
        self.activity = dictionary["activity"] as? [String] ?? [String]()
        self.video = dictionary["video"] as? String ?? ""
        self.videoURL = dictionary["videoURL"] as? URL ?? URL(fileURLWithPath: "")
        self.music = dictionary["music"] as? String ?? ""
       
        if let asDouble = dictionary["timestamp"] as? Double { self.timestampDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: asDouble) } else { self.timestampDate = Date() }
    }
```

//Here I am using JSONEncoder to be called in other parts of the code and to //help process the data to firebase

```
var dictionary: [String: Any] {
        let data = (try? JSONEncoder().encode(self)) ?? Data()
        return (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [.mutableContainers, .allowFragments]) as? [String: Any]) ?? [:]
    }
    
}
```

Comment: According to https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Timestamp `Timestamp` being `class Timestamp : NSObject, NSCopying`, it's not `Codable`, that's why it's throws the compiler error. Then, since you are using `JSONSerialization` `dictionary["timestamp"] as? Timestamp` should always be nil, since it's should be I guess a `Double`, not a `Timestamp`, meaning that the cast will fail. A quick way, would be to use a `Date` as said, but keep it `private`, and use a computed var to get `Timestamp` from that `Date`.

Comment: @Larme could you please provide detailed information on how to do that in the code?

Comment: `private var timestampDate: Date` `if let asDouble = dictionary["timestamp"] as? Double { self.timestampDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: asDouble) } else { self.timestampDate = Date() }` and `var timestamp: Timestamp { Timestamp(date: timestampDate) }`?

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond sooner. but what you provided me with still doesn't work. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Define doesn't work. Did you look at `data`? If you convert it to String, what's inside it? What's wrong?

Comment: It gives the same error in codable. Here ill update my solution and you can view it.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will not synthesize Codable for you since you have a coding key for a computed property. This is not supported, auto synthesis only works with stored properties. If you remove `timestamp` from your `CodingKeys` enum it should work fine, but your encoded JSON won’t contain the timestamp. If you need that in your output or parse it from input you will have to implement Codable yourself.

Comment: Just removed timestamp from coding keys enum. However, it doesn't doesn't conform to the protocol 'decodable'.

Comment: Check for other mismatches between properties and coding keys. There must be exactly one coding key for each stored property, nothing more or nothing less.

Answer (score 0):

Upon the initial question:

A way to do that would be to keep the `Date` as private, and use Timestamp as a computed value:

```
private var timestampDate: Date
var timestamp: Timestamp { Timestamp(date: timestampDate) }
```

This need a little changes in the CodingKeys, because `timestamp` doesn't exists for it, but `timestampDate` does now:

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    ...
    case timestampDate = "timestamp"
}
```

Now, there are still a few issues.

```
self.videoURL = dictionary["videoURL"] as? URL ?? URL(fileURLWithPath: "")
```

This shouldn't work, since you are getting JSON, and `URL` isn't really a JSON value.

Instead:

```
let videoURLString = dictionary["videoURL"] as? String ?? ""
self.videoURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: videoURLString)
```

Now, you might have an issue with the Date value, you need to tell the encoder what's the logic:

```
var dictionary: [String: Any] {
    do {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
        let data = try encoder.encode(self)
        let dict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
        return dict as? [String: Any] ?? [:]
    } catch {
        print("Error: \(error)")
        return [:]
    }
}
```

I used as reference date 1970, depending on your settings, you might change it when encoding or decoding.

Also, I did proper `do`/`try`/`catch`, please don't write `try?`. If there is an error, you won't see it, you are just ignoring them.

Now, it's unrelated, but in the `init(postId:dictionary:)` you don't read `postId` value. Did you meant `self.postId = dictionary["postId"] as? String ?? postId` ?

Instead of using `dictionary["someValue"]`, why not use `dictionary[CodingKeys.someValue.rawValue]`, avoiding you any typo error?

Comment: That worked very well! Thank you so much Larme. I really appreciate the help.